# How to copy a folder using the install command

Tags: arch-linux, command

I'm fixing a package in Arch Linux, and I still cannot understand properly how the `install` command works.

I've checked the `man` and is quite vague.

**My question is**: How can I copy a folder using `install` ?
Can't understand out how `-D` and `-d` flags work.

Is `install` the right tool to do this or should I stick to `mkdir` and `cp` ?

Comment: "More often than not, the installation process of the software will create sub-directories below the pkg directory. If it does not, however, makepkg will generate a lot of errors and you will need to manually create sub-directories by adding the appropriate mkdir -p commands in the build() function before the installation procedure is run." https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages#package.28.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `man install`:

```
-d, --directory
   treat all arguments as directory names; create all components of the specified directories

-D     
   create all leading components of DEST except the last, then copy SOURCE to DEST
```

**Demonstration :**

- `install -d` flag :

  ```
  $ install -d foo bar
  $ ls -l
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root  6 Sep  8 15:55 foo
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root  6 Sep  8 15:55 bar
  ```

See it created two directories named `foo` & `bar`

- `install -D` flag :

  ```
  $ touch test{1..3}
  $ ls -l
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test1
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test2
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test3
  $ install -D test1 test2 test3 bar
  $ ls -l bar/
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test1
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test2
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Sep  8 16:11 test3
  ```

It copied files `test1..3` to directory `bar`

**Conclusion**

I don't think `install` supports copying entire directory trees; it's normally used on files. You probably need to use `cp` or `rsync`.